# Using Jacoco in pom.xml + SonarQube

Tags: testing, junit, sonarqube, pom.xml, jacoco

I'm doing some tests with jUnit and now I have to check the code coverage with Jacoco (adding it at pom.xml) and SonarQube.

And this is where I don't know what I have to do with Jacoco or how to add it to pom.xml and later view it with SonarQube.

Comment: You can have a look at the official documentation : http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Code+Coverage+by+Unit+Tests+for+Java+Project and more specifically to the `Using JaCoCo` section.

Answer (score 0):

The best is to check this sample code showing how to have UT, IT and coverage using Jacoco: https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/master/projects/languages/java/code-coverage/combined%20ut-it/combined-ut-it-multimodule-maven-jacoco and this documentation will help : http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Code+Coverage+by+Integration+Tests+for+Java+Project